# Calculating TCP checksum with single TCP option - can it be done?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I was calculating TCP checksum and it was working perfectly fine but when I introduced single TCP option the algorithm got broken.

This is my function that I am using to copy the actual values to my checksum pointer

```
uint16_t tcp_chksum(struct iphdr *snd_iph, struct tcphdr *snd_tcph,struct mss *m)
{
    struct psuedo_header psh;

    psh.src_addr = snd_iph->saddr;
    psh.dst_addr = snd_iph->daddr;
    psh.rsvd = 0;
    psh.proto = IPPROTO_TCP;
    psh.len_tcp = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr)); /* No options, and no data */

    int pseudogram_size = sizeof(struct tcphdr) + sizeof(struct psuedo_header)+sizeof(struct mss);
    printf("sizeof with MSS = %d\n",pseudogram_size);
    //int pseudogram_size = sizeof(*snd_tcph) + sizeof(psh);
    char *pseudogram = malloc(pseudogram_size);

    memcpy(pseudogram, (char *)&psh, sizeof(struct psuedo_header));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct psuedo_header), snd_tcph, sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    uint8_t p=0x0;
    //memset(pseudogram+sizeof( struct psuedo_header)+sizeof(struct tcphdr),0,sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(pseudogram+sizeof(struct psuedo_header)+sizeof(struct tcphdr),m,sizeof(struct mss));

    return((csum1(pseudogram, pseudogram_size)));
    //return (htons(csum(snd_tcph, sizeof(struct my_tcph)) + csum(&psh, sizeof(struct psuedo_header))));
}
```

This line is sizeof that I will allocate, and assign values to allocated area and do checksum on it:

```
int pseudogram_size = sizeof(struct tcphdr) + sizeof(struct psuedo_header)+sizeof(struct mss);
```

So 4 extra bytes added in addition to my previous checksum space. if My `struct mss` looks like this:

```
struct mss
{
    uint8_t kind;
    uint8_t length;
    uint16_t val;
};
```

and following is my `struct psuedo_header`:

```
struct psuedo_header
{
    uint32_t    src_addr;
    uint32_t    dst_addr;
    uint8_t     rsvd;
    uint8_t     proto;
    uint16_t    len_tcp;
};
```

And this is how I am copying values to my checksum space:

```
memcpy(pseudogram, (char *)&psh, sizeof(struct psuedo_header));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct psuedo_header), snd_tcph, sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    uint8_t p=0x0;
    //memset(pseudogram+sizeof( struct psuedo_header)+sizeof(struct tcphdr),0,sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(pseudogram+sizeof(struct psuedo_header)+sizeof(struct tcphdr),m,sizeof(struct mss));
```

So as you can see here there is a simple technique is used to copy my values to allocated checksum space. But when I call this function and I seems just fine to call it:

```
uint16_t csum1(const void *data, const int length)
{
    printf("length = %d\n",length);
    uint16_t *accumalator = (uint16_t *)data;
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    /* Take care of the first 16-bit even blocks */
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i) {
        sum += *(accumalator+i);
        //printf("%x \n",*(accumalator+i));        
        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }

    /* Handle the ending partial block */
    if (length % 2 != 0) {
        accumalator = accumalator+ length/2; /* Point accumalator to the end block */
        uint16_t end_block = 0;
        memcpy(&end_block, accumalator, sizeof(length));
        sum += ntohs(end_block);
        //printf("%x \n",end_block);
        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }
    printf("_____________________________________________________");
    return htons(~sum);
}
```

The above function is simply operate on first some bytes in my case if since 4 bytes (32 bits options) added:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i) {
            sum += *(accumalator+i);
            //printf("%x \n",*(accumalator+i));        
            if (sum >= 0x10000) {
                sum -= 0xffff;
            }
        }
```

Above is operating until i==18 and `accumalator` is `uint16_t` so I am operating on all of `pseudogram` in the above loop.

So the size is 6 words x 4 == 24 bytes so my `tcphdr->doff=6` plus sizeof(struct psuedo_header) so it go in loop and take first length/2 bytes into consideration:

```
           tcp->doff=6;
```

I noticed that this line `int pseudogram_size = sizeof(struct tcphdr) + sizeof(struct psuedo_header)+sizeof(struct mss);` assign 36 to `pseudogram_size` so the and this condition doesn't get satisfied in my packet size case `if (length % 2 != 0)`

So there is nothing special about my checksum calculation, but why is it not working after adding 4 bytes option to my send buffer? Why is that, as it was working fine before I added the options and when was tcphdr->doff==5 without options?

Note: I am only using MSS option. Why after options addition my tcp checksum calculations are proven wrong?

In the last I am assigning tcp option MSS values like this:

```
mss_val->kind=2;
mss_val->length=4;
mss_val->val=ntohs(0x05b4);
```

Comment: `memcpy(&end_block, accumalator, sizeof(length));` If `length%2 != 0` there is only one byte to copy. Copy `sizeof(length)` bytes seems not ok in any way.

Comment: @Holger  `if (36 % 2 != 0)` this will never pass because the remainder is 0. So code inside if will not execute. Don't u know the answer of 36%2. It's 0 so why should I care about what's happening inside `if` curly brackets. Why are u focusing on this then? In wireshark. My option are not showing in Raw data. So I like to know which fields impact selection of number of bytes to show in wireshark raw packet bytes display.Is it ip->ihl. Or tcp->doff. When assign 40 plus 4 bytes for option to ip->ihl, wireshark shows error that size exceeded 40 bytes. And I a. Already assigning 6 words to doff

Comment: @Holger ur comment is completely useless unless u explain as to why I care about the what's inside if(36%2!=0)

Comment: Length is 36 my passed length parameter

Comment: The code was `if(length % 2 != 0` not `if(36 % 2 != 0)`. If 1 char is left but sizeof() chars are copied, the code seems defect. That's, what I wanted to say. Please, hth

Comment: @Holger all the packets I care having length parameter 36,so u comment was just distraction what might be the case.interestingly there is nothing wrong with iphdr but I get message in wireshark that `Expert Info (Error/Protocol): IPv4 total length exceeds packet length (40 bytes)` ihl is 5 and tot_len is 44 and its same as what I also received as packet but in my case it shows message ip checksum is correct too for my packet. why am getting this message `Expert Info (Error/Protocol): IPv4 total length exceeds packet length (40 bytes)` for my composed packet. does this error relates to tcphdr

Comment: @Holger does tcp checksum contains checksum on values too, this is least u can tell if u know

Comment: @Holger u and me just failed to notice this  `psh.len_tcp = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr)); /* No options, and no data */` and mistakes was clearly other places as well. Now I am getting correct tcp checksum plus MSS option is showing for my packet in wireshark.

Comment: @Holger any idea why I am keep getting SYN packets requests even though I am emitting perfectly correct SYN+ACK packets as response to SYN. Any wonders?

Comment: `if (sum >= 0x10000) {sum -= 0xffff; }` does this get executed? I am pretty sure this is not the correct algorithm.

Comment: and if total length of the packet is 40 bytes, and the value of IP total length is 44 bytes, then you get the error, that the value is 4 bytes longer than the packet.

Comment: @Effie ok. Also do u know if I have client socket fd without peered server fd. Then any how I can still establish tcp connection?;maybe through reading some socket file and write syn + ack packets In server to this socket file so my client socket `connect` gets successful and does not return -1